# How to speed up building .net solution in docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

My current setup:

```
App.sln
src\
----BaseProject\
-------------Dockerfile
-------------BaseProject.csproj
----ProjectA\
-------------Dockerfile
-------------ProjectA.csproj (references BaseProject)
----ProjectB\
-------------Dockerfile
-------------ProjectB.csproj (references BaseProject)
----ProjectC\
-------------Dockerfile
-------------ProjectC.csproj (references BaseProject)
```

Right now each project has its own dockerfile, and the containers are built in parallel, in the cloud. I wonder if it is possible to reuse build output to speed up build process.

I'm building whole solution using `docker compose build --parallel`, and publishing each project as separate container:

```
FROM sdk_image as build
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build --no-restore
RUN dotnet publish --no-build --no-restore  -o output

FROM runtime_image as runtime
COPY build/ouput .
RUN dotnet run myapp.dll
```

I've done some attempts to cache whole build in single layer but apparently output assemblies are so big that copying them takes more time than actual compilation.

I wonder if it's possible to speedup such build, maybe using docker volumes for nuget or build or similar mechanisms, or maybe deleting unnecessary files from build output?

Comment: You could add the `--no-build` option on the publish command, no need for that since it's already been done in the previous command.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this to the sample, but I am doing `--no-build` and `--no-restore` already. I want to more focus on sharing build results between different docker containers.

Comment: What (if anything) is shared between the various images?  As you've shown it, once you get past the `sdk_image`, each of the images is totally separate (they have their own language-level dependencies and source tree) and there's not much that can be deduplicated.

Comment: These are just normal .net projects depending on each other. So they have same runtime, and they all use `BaseProject` (or multiple base projects in reality).